# How to merge services from library's manifest?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have main app and a library. The library has one service. I need to merge definition of the service to main app, but it doesn't happen.

So, I have the AndroidManifest.xml of the library:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="ru.foobar.lib.test"
 android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <service
            android:name="ru.foobar.test.http.HttpService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process=":ru.foobar.test.http.HttpService" />
    <application />
</manifest>
```

I import this library to the main app by gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile project(':TestLib')
}
```

Then I start the service in onCreate method of the app:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, HttpService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

And I have the fail in logs:

```
W/ActivityManager(  375): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=ru.foobar.mainapp/ru.foobar.test.http.HttpService } U=0: not found
```

If I add the service definition to the manifest of main app, service starts fine.

Is it possible to merge manifests from main app and the library automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the service within your application manifest, so copy this

```
<service
   android:name="ru.foobar.test.http.HttpService"
   android:exported="false"
   android:process=":ru.foobar.test.http.HttpService" />
```

into your **application** `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Yes, I've told above that this method works. But question is how to leave full definition of the service in the library, without extra copying to app's menifest.

Comment: No you can't do it without defining it into your app